# How to come out of error switching euid to 0 and egid to 108 operations not permitted?

Tags: linux, sudo, logrotate

I tried to run the command `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` and it showed me the error

error switching euid to 0 and egid to 108: operations not permitted

and i want to run the logrotate file

Comment: Have you tried running the command with sudo?

Comment: Yes,  `sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` yes but though it runs there is no effect seen on /var/log

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the similar issue. `error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 0: Operation not permitted`. When I run this with sudo it runs but no effect in nginx/log directory. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: post the contents of your `logrotate.d/<my-awesome-logrotate>` file !